# how to make Asterisk Reject SIP call with code 503

Tags: asterisk

I'm writing a dial plan using phpAgi, there are some cases that it should reject an SIP call with error code 503 (service not available)

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Congestion command

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application Congestion 

  -= Info about application 'Congestion' =- 

[Synopsis]
Indicate the Congestion condition. 

[Description]
This application will indicate the congestion condition to the calling
channel.

[Syntax]
Congestion([timeout])

[Arguments]
timeout
    If specified, the calling channel will be hung up after the specified
    number of seconds. Otherwise, this application will wait until the calling
    channel hangs up.

[See Also]
Busy(), Progress(), Playtones(), Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hangup(34) will do it.

```
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup(34)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer and not the one above